Questionable workmanship on glass block windows
I hired a reputable company to replace four steel frame basement windows (original to 1945 house) with glass block. As far as appearance goes, I feel even I could have done a more professional job. What criteria should I use to decide whether to lodge a complaint? Are these issues purely superficial?
Out of level

Excessive (?) unrepaired damage to surrounding foundation


Rough mortar around edges


Excess mortar in glass crevices and vent corners


Generally the job could have been done a bit neater. It does show "pride of work" is a bit lacking.
That said I believe the contract as you stated was completed.
"...they will perform "fill-ins" on the "side gaps", That was done.
"... 2) trim may be damaged and will not be replaced."  This is the "unrepaired damage to the surrounding foundation."  That is not your foundation. It is the mortared trim around the old window. This is a matter of miscommunication about what "trim" is.
It could be neater, however I believe you got what you contracted for, since there was no indication from you that the block job would include "all finish trim and have a finished appearance."

Thank you, that's helpful.

As far as you have related, the contractor did as was asked. What grounds would there be for a "complaint" unless there was some specification agreed to beforehand that the completed job fails to meet? Nevertheless, baseless complaints sometimes bring results, but no-one on this site would be able to predict that in your case.

Few contracts lay out the work to be done in infinite detail. Even if mine did, as someone with little to no experience in this domain, I wouldn't be in a good position to evaluate it. Still, it's reasonable to expect a reputable company's work to conform to a standard generally agreed upon among members of the trade. That is the purpose of my post. Do people experienced with this kind of work understand this to be good workmanship? The relevant points from the contract are 1) they will perform "fill-ins" on the "side gaps", and 2) trim may be damaged and will not be replaced.
